# Export a very big amount of files from a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, blob

I'm using Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.6.0 and have a table recording a very big amount of files (GIF) with IDs (ID).

```
  Name                                      Type
  ----------------------------------------- ----------------------------
  ID                                        VARCHAR2(50)
  GIF                                       BLOB
```

And currently I'm using this piece of code to export the pictures:

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_name      VARCHAR2(50);
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       INTEGER := 1;
  l_count     INTEGER := 1;
  l_blob_len  INTEGER;
BEGIN
  for x in (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE) loop
        l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(x.GIF);
        l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('BLOBS',x.ID||'-'||l_count||'.gif','wb', 32767);
        l_pos := 1;
        WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
            DBMS_LOB.read(x.GIF, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
            UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
            l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
        END LOOP;
        UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
        l_count := l_count + 1;
  end loop;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF UTL_FILE.is_open(l_file) THEN
      UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

This code works well, **BUT the problem is, there're about 100 million rows in the table.** On my computer the export speed is about only 7 pictures/second.

So, is there any method that can accelerate the exporting? Thank you!

Comment: 100 million rows and 7 pictures/second are about 14 million seconds or about 170 days. So if you start 170 jobs in parallel this will take about one day if the jobs don't interfere. Is this an option?

Comment: @miracle173 Yes that's a good idea. But I'm a complete newbie and don't know how to carry out parallel jobs that don't interfere :( Any example?

Comment: Parallel jobs work best when the table and indexes are partitioned so that the optimizer can handle the multiple jobs in parallel without taking a performance hit.  If not a possibility, structure your PL/SQL to store data temporarily to a container and then use the JobID to assign the container data to the job.  Try maybe a parallel hint on the query itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ORA_HASH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions112.htm#SQLRF06313) function to split the table data in distinct groups. Look at the modified SELECT-FROM-MY_TABLE-clause. Run this script in three different sqlplus sessions and measure the number of files per seconds that are extracted.

script 0:

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_name      VARCHAR2(50);
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       INTEGER := 1;
  l_count     INTEGER := 1;
  l_blob_len  INTEGER;
BEGIN
  for x in (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where ora_hash(rowid,2,123)=0) loop
        l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(x.GIF);
        l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('BLOBS',x.ID||'-'||l_count||'.gif','wb', 32767);
        l_pos := 1;
        WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
            DBMS_LOB.read(x.GIF, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
            UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
            l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
        END LOOP;
        UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
        l_count := l_count + 1;
  end loop;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF UTL_FILE.is_open(l_file) THEN
      UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

script 1:

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_name      VARCHAR2(50);
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       INTEGER := 1;
  l_count     INTEGER := 1;
  l_blob_len  INTEGER;
BEGIN
  for x in (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where ora_hash(rowid,2,123)=1) loop
        l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(x.GIF);
        l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('BLOBS',x.ID||'-'||l_count||'.gif','wb', 32767);
        l_pos := 1;
        WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
            DBMS_LOB.read(x.GIF, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
            UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
            l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
        END LOOP;
        UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
        l_count := l_count + 1;
  end loop;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF UTL_FILE.is_open(l_file) THEN
      UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

script 2:

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_name      VARCHAR2(50);
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       INTEGER := 1;
  l_count     INTEGER := 1;
  l_blob_len  INTEGER;
BEGIN
  for x in (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where ora_hash(rowid,2,123)=2) loop
        l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(x.GIF);
        l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('BLOBS',x.ID||'-'||l_count||'.gif','wb', 32767);
        l_pos := 1;
        WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
            DBMS_LOB.read(x.GIF, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
            UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
            l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
        END LOOP;
        UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
        l_count := l_count + 1;
  end loop;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF UTL_FILE.is_open(l_file) THEN
      UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);
    END IF;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

If this works you can try to generate and start  more scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! Though I believe there might be a more elegant solution haha :-D

Comment: @Stan Yes,of course, but I hope one can get the idea.  Did you check if you can accelerate the export of data with this method?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet because there're other people's frequent IO jobs on that computer. I believe it should work when the computer is idle.

Comment: Verified. It worked!